# showing different buttons in the GUI depending on if statements

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement, javafx

I am trying to create a game that has two options: that the student can answer a question by introducing the answer or by clicking a button that contains the correct answer. I created the texfield and the buttons for the two types of questions and made if statements that depending on which type of question it is (the type is predetermined) if going to show the buttons or the textfield but it does not work (it does not get into the if).
My code looks like this:

```
    SanswerTextField = new TextField();
    SanswerTextField.setPrefWidth(300.0);
    SanswerTextField.setMinWidth(300.0);
    SanswerTextField.setMaxWidth(300.0);
    SanswerTextField.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    SanswerTextField.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 timesnewroman; -fx-base: #AE3522");



    SanswerButton1 = new Button();
    SanswerButton1.setPrefWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton1.setMinWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton1.setMaxWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton1.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    SanswerButton1.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 timesnewroman; -fx-base: #AE3522");


    SanswerButton2 = new Button();
    SanswerButton2.setPrefWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton2.setMinWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton2.setMaxWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton2.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    SanswerButton2.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 timesnewroman; -fx-base: #AE3522");



    SanswerButton3 = new Button();
    SanswerButton3.setPrefWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton3.setMinWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton3.setMaxWidth(50.0);
    SanswerButton3.setPrefHeight(50.0);
    SanswerButton3.setStyle("-fx-font: 30 timesnewroman; -fx-base: #AE3522");



    if(saveTypeQ.getText().equals("Choose Answer"))
    {
        SanswerButton1.setText(saveAnswer.getText());
        System.out.println("answer in button: " + SanswerButton1.getText());
        SanswerButton2.setText(saveAnswer.getText());
        SanswerButton3.setText(saveAnswer.getText());

        mathTestButtonPane.add(SanswerButton1,1,4);
        mathTestButtonPane.add(SanswerButton2,2,4);
        mathTestButtonPane.add(SanswerButton3,3,4);

        System.out.println("I am a question to choose an answer");
    }
    else if(saveTypeQ.getText().equals("Introduce Answer"))
    {
        mathTestButtonPane.add(SanswerTextField,1,4);
        System.out.println("I am a question to introduce an answer");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Not working");

    }
```

it is accessing always the else and I have no idea why. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. There is no definition `saveTypeQ` in your code.

Comment: Seems you haven't changed the button text later. Debugging might resolve the issue

Comment: saveTypeQ is just a Label in which the type of the question is left. The text of the label can be or Choose Answer or Introduce Answer. My GUI is a mess and is super long, a complete version would be way more confusing.

Comment: Abut the button text, at the moment I am just trying to access the if statement, IDK why it goes directly to the else.

Comment: It goes directly to the else because your saveTypeQ's text doesn't match either of the if cases. The question is why do you expect it to be different? Is the code being called within a listener of some type? Or is it being called on GUI creation? Also you've got a tremendous amount of code redundancy -- get rid of all that repeating code by using methods and you'll save yourself a lot of grief.